# Can onFormSubmit() trigger be triggered by something else other than a human submitting a Google form?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a Google form, it is set up to send emails on completion of the form. I followed http://www.labnol.org/internet/auto-confirmation-emails/28386/ pretty much exactly, just changing the text mainly. And it does indeed send emails on a submit, hooray!

The form itself has required questioned so a human shouldn't be able to submit the form without filling at least those questions in.

However, over the weekend (on Sunday 11th), three emails were sent with blank responses, even to the required questions!

So I think there are three likely explanations:

1. The required questions didn't work / structure of the form
   momentarily errored and allowed three blank responses from a human.
2. Some sort of robot / crawling script somehow triggered a null submit
3. The form was completed by a human and the data was not recorded, nor included in the email.

Do any / all of those explanations make sense / seem plausible?

And if 3 is the answer, do you know if it was a transitory, maybe documented, error that happened on Sunday?

Comment: A simple test is this: turn off, disable, your browser javascript, then see if you can submit the form. If you can, it means there's no server side validation happening. If the form disappears when you disable javascript, it would be harder, but not impossible, to submit it, but in all cases, if the form submits either to itself, or another page, there should be server side validation happening. Bots crawl endlessly looking for such forms, since the norm is poor or incomplete validation, it has always been worth their while to do so.

Comment: I disabled JavaScript and I could submit the form. The form submits to a Google Spreadsheet, is it possible to incorporate server side validation?

Comment: If you can submit the form without javascript, then so can every bot on the planet. So that actually answers your question. Javascript should NEVER be considered as more than a user friendly way to keep bad data from being entered. Server side validation is outside the scope of your question, that's a function of your ability to do it, and the flexibility of the various scripts you downloaded, etc. If you put a form up on the internet, you should also accept responsibility for what is put into that form, otherwise you are another bot resource.

Comment: I should be more precise: server side validation wouldn't stop the form from completing, that's the job of js validation, but it would handle the null data or bad data or hack attempt data on the server side, and take the appropriate steps at that point. Note that I"m not posting an answer because I don't deal with 3rd party scripts or tools, which are the tags on your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see why a bot could not submit a google form. The onSubmit trigger is just as it sounds. As soon as the form is submitted the google script runs so regardless of what sends the information as long as it was submitted to the form the script will run.

This scrip does a check against blank data for the text body of the e-mail but nothing else.

I have tested this and can confirm that even if your google form has a question set as required, if it is a text or paragraph entry then all you have to do is enter space and it will consider that valid data. All form submissions should be stored on a google spreadsheet so I would recommend checking the spreadsheet responses to see if the cell is actually blank or if it contains data like ' '.

Personally I always use specific ranges when doing an auto response or if I need to work with data from a form submission. Generally data should always be in the same place on the spreadsheet.

Your script runs whenever a form is submited. So if a bot can bypass the check if question is empty and still submit it then your script will run anyway.

Comment: The cells are blank in the spreadsheet, i.e. don't contain ' '.. In the confirmation email it echoes all non empty responses, and it echoed nothing.

Comment: @Timmy You can use the even object for additional validation then. The e variable in the SendConfirmationMail function can be checked for null values and terminated if found. So if a bot bypassed the required question check it would then be stopped at the beginning of the script.